# Boolean value always the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm trying to set up player turns in a simple unity game, however my boolean for player turn (it is a two-player game) doesn't seem to be changing at all. The value of the player turn boolean is important for code later on in my unity script, hence is relied on, however it is stuck to one value no matter what changes I make. I have searched for an answer but have found none that suits my context, so I will just dump my issue here.

Code is as follows:

```
if (TurnP1 = true)
{ 
    TurnP1 = false;
}
else
{
    TurnP1 = true;  
}
DropPiece(columnNumber, TurnP1);
TestForWinner();
TestForDraw();
```

Help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: It can be done much shorter without `if`: `TurnP1 = !TurnP1`.

Comment: `if (TurnP1 = true)` is an assignment. Use `if (TurnP1 == true)` to test equality.

Comment: Do not edit your question and change title to "Fixed" or "Solved". Just check the correct answer and leave comments under answers, if you want. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that here you actually do an assignment:

```
if (TurnP1 = true)
```

It is the same as:

```
TurnP1 = true;
if (TurnP1) {
    TurnP1 = false;
} else {
    TurnP1 = true;
}
```

This condition is always `true`.
You need to change this code to

```
if (TurnP1 == true)
```

However, all these lines of code can be replaced with negation:

```
TurnP1 = !TurnP1;

DropPiece(columnNumber, TurnP1);
TestForWinner();
TestForDraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TurnP1 = true
```

is assignment, you need `if (TurnP1)` to check whether TurnP1 is true, or simply

```
DropPiece(columnNumber, !TurnP1);
TestForWinner();
TestForDraw();
```